# Passar parâmetros via POST com node.js

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando acessar um serviço que retorna um XML [Descrição do serviço](http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/Port/DownloadArqs/download02.htm)  e lá fala que tenho que informar alguns parâmetros via POST. É a primeira vez que estou tendo que fazer isso e não estou conseguindo. Alguém pode dar uma luz?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post do stackoverflow em inglês [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158933/how-to-make-an-http-post-request-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Usando somente Node puro, você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
const querystring = require('querystring')
const https = require('https')
const postData = querystring.stringify({
  txtLogin: 'login',
  txtSenha: 'senha',
  txtData: 'data'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'www.rad.cvm.gov.br',
  port: 80,
  path: '/DOWNLOAD/SolicitaDownload.asp',
  method: 'POST'
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8')
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`Corpo: ${chunk}`);
  })
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Nenhum dado a mais na resposta.');
  })
})

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Problemas no request: ${e.message}`)
})

req.write(postData)
req.end()
```